# Checking to see if symbol exists in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

If I execute a call to the "security" function on a symbol that used to exist, but does no longer, like so:

```
   sLow = security("TSX_DLY:AKG", "240", low)
```

the statement will execute without errors even though the symbol "TSX_DLY:AKG" no longer exists, but if I attempt to use sLow, it will stop working and give me a "Study Error" with details indicating a  "Resolve_error". It won't even work if I try to check if sLow is valid even before attempting to use it. An explanation I read as to why, is in Michel_T's answer from about 11 months ago in the following article:

[how to check if pair exist in security function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60126119/how-to-check-if-pair-exist-in-security-function)

Have there been any changes to Pine Script since then that would allow this to be properly dealt with when using "security"?

If not, is there another way to check if a symbol exists that can be properly handled without causing an execution error?

Thanks

Comment: Michel_T's way works for existing symbols with empty history only.

Comment: I have the same issue, it's quite frustrating that this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

In Pine Script V5, use `ignore_invalid_symbol=true`